# how to specify a BIGINT in a rails scaffold?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to create a model in ruby that uses a `BIGINT` datatype (as opposed to the `INT` done by `:integer`).

I have search all over Google, but all I seem to find is "run an SQL statement to alter the table to a BIGINT" - This seems a bit hack-ish to me, so I wanted to know if there was a way to specify a bigint in the ruby system like `:big_int` or something

Any ideas?

Comment: Edited the title to say "rails scaffold" instead of "ruby scaffold", hope you didn't mind ;)

Comment: @August - Nope not at all. I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://agilewebdevelopment.com/plugins/mysql_bigint) is a plug-in that changes the way ActiveRecord interacts with MySQL using the limit parameter and integer columns. It'll save you from the SQL-statement hackiness.

```
 t.column "myBigInt", :integer, :limit => 5, :null=> false # uses MySQL bigint
```

Answer (score 2):

A little too late for the answer but for future readers.

In newer versions of Rails, `bigint` is natively supported.

```rb
add_column :table_name, :column_name, :bigint
```